# Is it possible to inherit from the main class in Objective-C (Xcode / iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I don't have direct access to the main AppDelegate file (i'm using SDL2 app where the AppDelegate file is compiled)

For testing purpose, is it possible possible to add a hook to the main application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or to make an inherit class in Xcode ?

Answer (score 2):

A solution that may address your problem is to register for the `UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification` in a class load method. E.g.

```
+ (void)load {
    NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self 
                      selector:@selector(appDidLaunch)
                          name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
                        object:nil];
}

+ (void)appDidLaunch:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *options = [notification userInfo];
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I use this method for implementing ios push notification ? Tutorial suggest that it must be implemented in the AppDelegate file